# How do I disable a make target with the perl MakeMaker module?

Tags: perl, module, packaging, makemaker

I'm using ExtUtils::MakeMaker to package my perl module but I don't want the makefile to copy files anywhere on the system.
I need to disable the "install" target and instead tell the user that this makefile only supports "make dist" when he types "make install".

Comment: Just curious: Why not let the user run `make install` if they want to? Otherwise, how would they use your modules you're producing?

Comment: Because the application is dependent on several system administration choices like "Which database backend am I going to use", etc. and just copying the modules to any directory on the system makes no real sense. I'm just offering the Makefile.PL as a helper module for Linux distributions modules packagers.

Answer (score 1):

Define `MY::install` in your `Makefile.PL` file:

```
sub MY::install {
    "install ::\n\techo You should run \\'make dist\\', not \\'make install\\'"
}
```

The function should return the text you want to use to replace the `install` section of the Makefile.

You could make `make install` a synonym for `make dist` with:

```
sub MY::install [ "install :: dist\n" }
```

Doc: [Overriding MakeMaker methods](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Overriding-MakeMaker-Methods)

Comment: A slightly updated version of your answer is exactly what I was looking for:  `sub MY::install {
    "install ::\n\t\$(info You should run 'make dist', not 'make install')"
}
`  Thanks

Comment: I was just going to suggest putting `PREFIX => '/dev/null,` in the `WriteMakefile` structure. You can run `make install`, but it won't work. Nice to know you can actually override the targets themselves.